# cxf client unable to find imported wsdl

Tags: java, cxf, webservice-client

I am novice in web service, I have a scenario.

CXF client stub is unable to locate imported wsdl in its parent wsdl. I mean I have A.wsdl which has `wsdl:import` of B.wsdl. I generated client stub for A.wsdl using maven cxf plugin. 
When I create service object passing A.wsdl, I am getting file not found exception for B.wsdl.

How to make this work?

[Maven conf]

```
<plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate-sources</id>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <defaultOptions>
                            <frontEnd>jaxws21</frontEnd>
                            <validateWsdl>true</validateWsdl>
                            <faultSerialVersionUID>1</faultSerialVersionUID>
                            <allowElementRefs>true</allowElementRefs>
                            <bindingFiles>
                                <bindingFile>src/main/resources/binding/ESB-BSSAPI/Common_JAXB_binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                                <bindingFile>src/main/resources/binding/ESB-BSSAPI/Common_JAXWS_binding.xjb</bindingFile>
                            </bindingFiles>
                            <autoNameResolution>true</autoNameResolution>
                        </defaultOptions>
                        <sourceRoot>src/main/java</sourceRoot>
                        <wsdlOptions>
                            <wsdlOption>
                                <wsdl>src/main/resources/wsdl/provider/ESB-BSSAPI/Accounts.wsdl</wsdl>
                                <packagenames>
                                    <packagename>com.company.platform.il.esb.accounts</packagename>
                                </packagenames>
                            </wsdlOption>
                        </wsdlOptions>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-rt-databinding-jaxb</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.1</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
                    <version>2.6</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.apache.cxf.xjcplugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>cxf-xjc-ts</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.4</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-fluent-api</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jaxb2-basics</artifactId>
                    <version>0.6.4</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </plugin>
```

All wsdls are located under **src/main/resources/wsdl/provider/ESB-BSSAPI/** folder

In Accounts.wsdl file i have wsdl:imports

```
<wsdl:import namespace="http://soap.crmapi.util.company.com/common/xsd/Common-v1.1" location="Common_interface_1_1.wsdl" />
<wsdl:import namespace="http://soap.crmapi.util.company.com/common/xsd/Common-v2.0" location="Common_interface_2_0.wsdl" />
<wsdl:import namespace="http://soap.crmapi.util.company.com/common/exception/xsd/2008/08" location="Common_faults_1_0.wsdl" />
<wsdl:import namespace="http://soap.crmapi.util.company.com/accounts/xsd/Accounts-v1.0" location="Accounts_interface_1_0.wsdl" />
<wsdl:import namespace="http://soap.crmapi.util.company.com/accounts/xsd/Accounts-v1.1" location="Accounts_interface_1_1.wsdl" />
<wsdl:import namespace="http://soap.crmapi.util.company.com/accounts/xsd/Accounts-v1.2" location="Accounts_interface_1_2.wsdl" />
<wsdl:import namespace="http://soap.crmapi.util.company.com/accounts/xsd/Accounts-v2.0" location="Accounts_interface_2_0.wsdl" />
```

In Java i am creating Service object and trying to invoke getAccountProfileV2 operation

```
ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource("wsdl/provider/ESB-BSSAPI/Accounts.wsdl");
                File wsdlLocation = classPathResource.getFile();
                com.company.platform.il.esb.accounts.AccountService managementService = 
                        new com.company.platform.il.esb.accounts.AccountService(wsdlLocation.toURL());
                AccountsPortTypeV20 service = managementService.getAccountsSOAP11PortHttp();
//.....

GetAccountProfileV2Response accountProfileQueryResult = service.getAccountProfileV2(accountProfileV2);
```

Upon invoking operation, i get `FileNotFoundException for Common_interface_1_1.wsdl`
It is actually trying to search inside `Wildfly/bin` folder

Thanks in advance
Raj

Comment: Have you created the WSDL's? How your wsdl are located to each other? Also add the maven configuration.

Comment: Hi Garry, i have edited question with relevant sources. WSDLs are taken from producer so i havent created these wsdls.